# How to view diff of several changsets?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Someone worked on a feature for a few days during which he made several commits. Other people have committed changes too while he was working so his commits are not consecutive.

How can I code review his commits as a whole, without viewing intermediary changes? And I don't want to view changes made by other people.

I can use TortoiseHG's search feature and type the issue number in the search box to locate his 5 changesets. Ideally I'd multi-select the changesets and then right-click and 'show diff' but that does not work.

I don't mind if the solution implies cloning the repository again and rewriting history in order to collapse the changesets (I'd discard that repo after).

*Note: we don't want to change our workflow to ensure that features are pushed as a single commit.*

---

Attempt 1:

- update to a rev before his work
- multi-select his changesets then 'Copy selected as patch'
- apply the patch to my working directory

result: that created rejects so that solution is not ideal

Attempt 2:

- use 'import to MQ' on the changesets with the intent of qfolding the them

result: 'import to MQ' fails: `abort: revision 19630 is the root of more than one branch`.

Comment: To clarify "non-consecutive": for user A and his changes A*, the chageset history looks like A1-B1-A2-C1-A3  in a linear fashion with others' work intersperced in the change history.

Comment: You seem to have interdependent changes in your branch, I doubt any work on the history can solve your issue. You can try to update to latest and backout the non-user changesets, too (attempt 1 in reverse), but it might still be in vain.

Comment: ...Or attempt 1, but by grafting in a temporary branch the user's changesets.

Answer (score 0):

> we don't want to change our workflow to ensure that features are pushed as a single commit.

Okay, you can use any workflow, I will just note: "Branch per Task"

- will not require "feature in single commit"
- eliminates a lot of (future) headache

In current state without cloning|rewriting history you can

- forget about GUI
- Get (some way) list of all changesets, related to be-reviewed feature
- In console use `hg diff -c CSET -c CSET2 ... -c CSETN <other options>` (where every `CSETX` is changeset, related to feature